# Expression Builder in QGIS "left" or "strpos" not working

Tags: regex, postgresql, qgis

I have a table in QGIS with full names and I want to parse into first name(s) and last name. I’ve created the columns and am using expression builder to do this. Here's what I'm trying and it's not working. `left( "name",strpos( "name", " ") )` with `name` being the full name. I've tried just putting in `strpos( "name", " ")` to see if things are working and nothing shows up. I click on Update Selected and nothing changes. I've tried putting the whole expression in `last_name = "name",strpos( "name", " ") )` and no luck. QGIS on Mac OSX. PostgreSQL

What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
left( "name", strpos( "name", ' ') )
```

**Explanation**

In expressions `"something"` denotes a column called *something*.

So in your expression

```
left( "name",strpos( "name", " ") )
```

strpos takes a column and a string argument. You passed "name" for the column which is good, but your second argument `" "` is actually looking for a **column** called `<space>`. To quote a string, you use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you again.  I swore I tried this. But this works. I've written it down and hope to remember it.